# Convergence of integral for $p > 1$.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I want to evaluate the integral $$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{x \log_e(x)[\log_e(\log_e(x))]^p}dx,$$ for $p >1$. My attempt has been to let $u = \log_e(x)$. Then $du = \frac{1}{x} dx$ and the integral reduces to \begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\log_e(2)}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u[u(u)]^p}du. 
\end{eqnarray*} I don't understand what to do from here.

Comment: I personally think it would be easier to read in you replaced your integral with $$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x\ln(x)\ln^p(\ln x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Let $\ln(\ln(x))=u$ ${}{}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your integral as $$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{\ln^p(\ln x)\ln(x)\,x}$$

you may notice that the denominator is reminiscent of some chain-rule derivative. Take the substitution

$$u=\ln(\ln x)$$
$$du=\frac1{\ln(x)}\frac1x\,dx$$

And you get

$$\begin{align}
\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{\ln^p(\ln x)\ln(x)\,x} &= \int_{u_1}^{u_2} u^{-p}\,du \\
&= \left. \frac{u^{1-p}}{1-p} \right|_{u_1}^{u_2} \\
&=\left. \frac{\left[\ln(\ln x)\right]^{1-p}}{1-p} \right|_{2}^{\infty} \\
\end{align}$$

Since $\ln(\ln x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, the first term goes to $0$, and you are left with

$$-\frac{\left[ \ln(\ln 2) \right]^{1-p}}{1-p}$$

Comment: Something about this felt… sketchy… I would appreciate any reviews of my work.

Comment: $\int u^{-p}du=\dfrac{u^{-p+1}}{-p+1}$.

Comment: @MyGlasses Thank you! Does it look better now?